# Understanding how numpy arrays are laid out in memory

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use build OpenGL textures in python using numpy, but I'm running into problems because I can't predict how numpy arrays will be organized in memory.  The example program below (which should run as-is) illustrates my confusion:

```
from pylab import *

array_by_hand = array(
    [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]], dtype='uint8')

layers = 1 * ones((2, 2)), 2 * ones((2, 2)), 3 * ones((2, 2)), 4 * ones((2, 2))
array_from_layers = dstack(layers)
array_from_layers = array_from_layers.astype('uint8')

print array_by_hand; print
print array_from_layers; print

print ' '.join(x.encode('hex') for x in array_by_hand.data)
print ' '.join(x.encode('hex') for x in array_from_layers.data)
print
print all(array_by_hand == array_from_layers)                 # True
print str(array_by_hand.data) == str(array_from_layers.data)  # False
```

Although the two arrays are equivalent as far as python is concerned, the are laid out differently in memory and therefore displayed differently by OpenGL.  Can someone explain why this is happening and how I might coerce both arrays to the same format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call the tostring method instead, it converts the array to C-contiguous layout:

```
>>> array_by_hand.tostring() == array_from_layers.tostring()
True
```

The reason the string is different in your case is because of the `dstack` call. It tries to be smart about stacking arrays together by simply combining the underlying data of the source arrays and then changing [numpy's stride information](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/internals.code-explanations.html#memory-model). This results in the array not being in C-contiguous layout.

Comment: It was kind of a surprise to me that, when copying the data in the `.astype('uint8')` step, the copy wasn't rearranged into C-contiguous form.

Comment: You could also use `np.ascontiguousarray` to ensure the memory layout you want... also `.flatten()` will always copy your array, even if it does not have to. And really `.tostring()` already ensures `C` contiguous output.

Comment: .tostring() was not C contiguous without calling .flatten() when I tried

Comment: Try again :), it takes an order parameter, but it seems to not even support 'K' and it defaults to 'C'

Comment: You're right, I tried again and it worked. Not sure what happened last time. Updating answer.